# PyCharm: How to autocomplete on a given function argument?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have something similar to this python code:

---

path1/argument.py

```
arg1 = 5
arg2 = 6
arg3 = 7
```

---

path2/argument.py

```
arg1 = 1
arg2 = 2
arg3 = 3
```

---

function.py

```
def myfunction(argument):
    argument.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.path.append(sys.argv[1])
    import argument
    myfunction(argument)
```

How can I tell PyCharm that argument is the module in argument.py ?
so that when I the '.' it would autocomplete the fields for me?

The path to where the argument lives is passed in through the command line

Comment: I don't think you can, and this is an abuse of the import system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the directory as "source" in your project window where argument is located in PyCharm to make it read its content, and recognise it as an import, and make it able to autocomplete.

When you mark the directory that contains argument.py as source you can do:

```
import argument
argument.a # Now PyCharm should recognise and suggest you arg1 arg2 etc
```

Comment: okay so this would work as long as I don't import dynamically?

Comment: Sorry i cant chek it now with dynamic import, but i guess it should work